# Is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}$ $(\sqrt[\leftroot{-3}\uproot{3}n]{a}-1)^p$ divergent or convergent?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I know $a>1,p>0$. I've tried the direct comparison test, but I can´t find a sequence $b_{n} > a_{n}$ whose sum converges, or a sequence $b_{n} < a_{n}$ whose sum diverges.

Comment: Here's a hint: Can you show, for any $a$, there is an $N$ so that if $n>N$, $\sqrt[n]{a}<2$? If you could, why would that help?

Comment: *Hint.* Use the limit comparison test with the $p$-series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^{-p}$ using the fact $$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a^{1/n}-1}{1/n} = \log a > 0. $$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

As this is a series with positive terms, you can use asymptotic analysis:
$$\sqrt[n]a-1=\mathrm e^{\tfrac{\ln a}n}-1\sim_\infty\frac{\ln a}n,\quad\text{so }\enspace\bigl(\sqrt[n]a-1\bigr)^p\sim_\infty\frac{\ln^pa}{n^p}.$$